# Creating a Search Bar with cascading functionality with Python

Tags: python, tkinter, uisearchbar

I have been wondering if it possible to create a search bar with cascading functionality using an entry widget in tkinter or if there is another widgets that can be used to achieve this aim, through out my time in desktop application development i've only been able to create one where you will have to type in the full name of what you want to search, then you'd write a query that gets the entry and gets what ever information you want from the database, this is very important for me because it limits me, especially when i want to create an application for a store where there a a lot of items you could just type the first letter of an item and it automatically shows you the items with that first letter. please i'd really appreciate if there is an answer to this...

Comment: Maybe the `AutocompleteCombobox` widget in the [ttkwidget](https://github.com/RedFantom/ttkwidgets/) module does what  you want.

Comment: thank you, it is not exactly what i'm looking for but that would work @j_4321

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is bind a function on `<Any-KeyRelease>` to filter the data as the user types. When the bound function is called, get the value of the entry widget then use that to get a filtered list of values.

Here's an example that uses a fixed set of data and a listbox to show the data, but of course you can just as easily do a database query and display the values however you wish.

```
import tkinter as tk

# A list of all tkinter widget class names
VALUES = [cls.__name__ for cls in tk.Widget.__subclasses__()]

class Example():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self.root)
        self.listbox = tk.Listbox(self.root)
        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self.root, command=self.listbox.yview)
        self.listbox.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)

        self.entry.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.listbox.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand=True)

        self.entry.bind("<Any-KeyRelease>", self.filter)

        self.filter()

    def filter(self, event=None):
        pattern = self.entry.get().lower()
        self.listbox.delete(0, "end")
        filtered = [value for value in VALUES if value.lower().startswith(pattern)]
        self.listbox.insert("end", *filtered)

example = Example()
tk.mainloop()
```